# iOS iPhone LaunchImage Landscape

Tags: ios, iphone, splash-screen, landscape, portrait

I have created an application which works only in landscape. But the splash screen is not shown when launching the app.

As you can see here my app runs in landscape.

[image]

But in my image catalog I can only add portrait images. (There is no setting here for the iPhone on the right side, with the iPad I can choose portrait and landscape).

When I launch the app with these images and having "Landscape Right" selected. My splash screen does not show up. When I check Portrait above the splash screen does work (but the app doesn't work correctly in Portrait) so I can't do that.

[image]

I've created an single view application, with only landscape checked and the splash images added, but it doesn't show a thing. Unless I check portrait. You can download this test project here. http://cl.ly/X1nK

Answer (score 0):

You can design your image so that it appears to be landscape.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this - [Apple launch image details](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/LaunchImages.html)

In your case, Same image will work for you. You just have to design image in a way, which indicates user that,This app support only landscape mode.

Hope this help.

Comment: This is what I did. But when the app starts there is no splash screen. It only shows up when I check portrait mode, but then my app is rotated wrongly.